# Geo specific page for Australia

Tags: c#, localization, seo, redirect

I have read [this article from Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages.html).

and have added these `meta` tags to the head of each page.

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.theaustralianwebsite.com.au/" hreflang="en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.thegeneralwebsite.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

as you can see, we have a different domain for the australian visitors with a totally different website. Not just the same content localized, but everything is different.

What would be the best approach to redirect australians that hit the general website to the australian website?
An SEO expert advised me to use a database which maps ip-addresses to countries and redirects based on that. I would prefer a solution based on first client browser language settings. Like this http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales

So what would be the best solution for me to redirect users? and should I use javascript or serverside solution (C# .net in my case, something like this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208935)

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages != null)
    {
        string culture = Request.UserLanguages[0].ToLower();
        if (culture.Contains("au"))
             Response.Redirect("http://www.theaustralianwebsite.com.au/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try and break down my answer into multiple parts.

**Identify a country by IP**

There are a number of free and paid services which offer the ability to geo-map an IP address to a country; [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-precision-country-service) (commercial) and [HostIP](http://www.hostip.info/) (free but limited to 1000 requests per day) are two such services. You will find a high degree of accuracy with MaxMind, and a good level of coverage for HostIP.

I would strongly recommend using a service rather than building your own detection and identification service as it's extremely difficult to do with any degree of accuracy.

It is probably worth mentioning that nothing is 100% accurate. For example I live in Australia but may use my corporate VPN which tunnels me through Singapore.

**Redirection**

I live in Australia and have experienced many automatic redirections to global sites. As a customer I can tell you this is extremely annoying, and usually I cannot close down the browser tab soon enough.

In the majority of cases it is not advisable to automatically redirect users, instead you should simply inform them that they may receive a better experience from visiting the local site. There are may ways to achieve this like displaying an [alert or notification](http://ui-patterns.com/users/1/collections/modal-windows/screenshots).

If you are concerned about providing a good user experience (and you should be) try posting a question on https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as an Australian citizen, can you tell me what the http accept language header looks like for you? I agree on the alert/notification. But I am looking for "solid" detection. And ip does not work because of proxy/vpn's so language accept header seems the best to localize content for users. But I am afraid that australians have english as accept header rather than 'au'